# What does the Platform option in Sentry do?

Tags: programming-languages, project-management, sentry, raven

As you can see here, while a Sentry project has a setting for platform, it has instructions (sections to the left) for connecting any platform to its logging:

[image]

Furthermore it works when logging from multiple programming languages, and it's not obvious in the stream, which errors are from which programming languages until you go to the individual error.

Is the platform setting just marking a project as one language, so you may have one project for Python, one project for JS, etc. or are there more important ramifications of changing the "platform" of a project? I saw in the [changelog](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog/) that "Sentry will now ask for your project’s platform." since 5.2 although it isn't clear what this option is for, as it will apparently log from any language's Raven logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [best answer I've found](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/1286) (and it's still pretty vague):

> This is mostly so we can apply some sane defaults on how to render the stack frames visually.
>
> We definitely don't prevent you from sending a JavaScript error to a project that is set to Python, for example.